# Continuos Test Flight upload .apk Android apps

Tags: android, testflight

I'm wondering if there is some kind of solution like this one for iOS for Android, in order to upload .apk to Test Flight:

[Is there any automatic Testflight upload script on application archiving?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496266/is-there-any-automatic-testflight-upload-script-on-application-archiving)

So we need to upload .apk files to test Flight repository using some kind of script from command line.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Upload API](https://testflightapp.com/api/doc/) from TestFlight.
You can create some sort of batch script you can execute at certain times.
For example:

```
curl http://testflightapp.com/api/builds.json 
-F file=@testflightapp.apk
-F api_token='your_api_token' 
-F team_token='your_team_token' 
-F notes='This build was uploaded via the upload API' 
-F notify=True 
-F distribution_lists='Internal, QA'
```